# Tumblr API - 'tag crawling' script doesn't show the images

Tags: javascript, ajax, tumblr

I have this so far. It should grab the images from 'cyberpunk' tag and post it to `<body>`, but it doesn't work. Why? More information about Tumblr API can be found [here](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#tagged-method).

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function (){
    var link = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/tagged?tag=cyberpunk";
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url : link,
      dataType: "jsonp", 
      data: {
          api_key: "PgAKpKfv1Tcjo1uhsKEuriThhwH9XDJonRobaGwckw8RJt2tos"
      }
    }).done(function( data ) {
      $.each(data.response.posts, function(){
        var _photos = this.photos;

        $.each(_photos, function(){
          $('body').append("<img src='" + this.original_size.url + "'/>");
        });
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its just `data.response`, not `data.response.posts`, so

```
//your code...
//..

 $.each(data.response, function(){ //
//.. rest of your code
```

Comment: Yeah, that works! How can I modify the code to make the script crawl from different tags randomly? I'm not sure if I should make another question for that.

Comment: you should make another question since it's out of the scope of this question.